# How reliable is to user request.getHeader("Referer");

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on Spring-MVC application and have to take care of a use-case in which i have to redirect back user to same location from where he/she came from after successful Login to my application.

i came across using HTTP `Referer` header like

```
final String refer = request.getHeader("Referer");
```

but after doing some R&D i came across various threads saying that `Referer` is not reliable and and and firewall and well browser can block it which can make my application not working properly.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Or in spring how can i get information about the location(URL) from where user came so that i can save it somewhere and can retrieve it once user get logged in successfully. i have seen similar functionality in Spring security.

Comment: Which version of Spring Security you use?

Comment: What happens if you simply remove the XML attribute `default-target-url`?

Comment: @PauKiatWee: i am not using spring security but i know same is implimented in spring security

Comment: @JoopEggen: i am not using Spring security :(

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Referer_hiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple actually:

- A non-authenticated user tries to access a protected resource in your app
- A security filter intercepts the request
- The filter stores the URL of the accessed protected resource in a session attribute
- The filter forwards to the login screen
- Once the login is successful, the URL is retrieved from the session, and the user is redirected to this URL

I would only do this is the protected resource is accessed using a GET request. Another variant is to store the URL of the protected resource in a hidden field of the login form.

Comment: What about the case when user click on the login button directly, say i am on a product detail page, user click on the header section for Login link.How will i redirect him/her back to product detail page as i don't see a interceptor in action here

Comment: Well, make sure to generate a link/button to the login page that contains the URL of the current page: `<a href="login?destination=theCurrentUrl">Login</a>`. But I wouldn't care much about this situation: if a user goes to the login page without being forced to, it probably means that he wants to leave the current page anyway. So redirecting it to another page after login probably makes more sense (a page like "Here's what you can do now you're authenticated", or simply the home page)

Comment: i understand your point but this is what client requirement and i can't do much as they are fixed :(

Comment: I would be against storing the URL in session attribute in case of an internet application. It creates a DOS vulnerabilty. Using something as login?destination=theCurrentUrl seems better solution in any case.